# PyQGIS: Add user input as parameter/expression in Raster Calculator

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, expression, parameters

I want to use Raster Calculator in my Python script in QGIS. The expression is easy - I create new raster with two values (0,1) where I get 1 if pixel value is higher than certain threshold ("A > threshold"). My code works perfectly if the threshold value is given in code by default (ex. "A > 0.3"), but I want user to choose the value.

Please do anybody know how to add variable as parameter into expression? Below is my code.

```
threshold, tOK = QInputDialog.getDouble(parent, "Threshold", "threshold", 0.3, 0.0, 0.9, 3)

input_raster = QgsRasterLayer('path/raster.tif', 'raster')      
output_raster = 'path/rastr_calc2.tif'

parameters = {'INPUT_A' : input_raster,'BAND_A' : 1,
    'FORMULA' : '(A > threshold)', 
    'OUTPUT' : output_raster}

processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:rastercalculator', parameters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Point is to get user input and add this input into string which I save into variable "formula". Then this variable is an input string to formula parameter of raster calculator.

```
threshold, tOK = QInputDialog.getDouble(parent, "Threshold", "threshold", 0.3, 0.0, 0.9, 3)

input_raster = QgsRasterLayer('path/raster.tif', 'raster')      
output_raster = 'path/rastr_calc2.tif'

formula = "(A>{})".format(threshold)

parameters = {'INPUT_A' : input_raster,'BAND_A' : 1,
'FORMULA' : formula, 
'OUTPUT' : output_raster}

processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:rastercalculator', parameters)
```